# article problem

Tags: definite-articles

> Apart from disposing of rubbish carefully and changing the water that
>   hold plants every week, name two other methods to prevent the
>   accumulation of stagnant water.

Can I omit the "the" before "accumulation"? I always think the use of articles is one of the most difficult thing in English learning.

Comment: If the noun ends in -ation, you cannot go wrong: you can omit the article, use "the", or use "a|an".   It doesn't matter.

Comment: Accumulation of water in the root system is to be avoided. An accumulation of water in the root system is to be avoided. The accumulation of water in the root system is to be avoided.

Comment: Why not go for `to prevent stagnant water accumulation`?

Answer (score 1):

*The* is optional here, but I would keep it in.  To my ear, the sentence sounds terse without it.